# Vue JS - How to hide previous dropdown content

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a Dropdown the problem is that I cannot hide the dropdown content when clicking on another Dropdown

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div
      v-for="(i, index) in contentInfo"
      :key="index"
      @click="showContent(i)"
      class="dropdown"
    >
      <div class="dropdown-title">
        <p>{{ i.text }}</p>
        <div v-show="i.show">
          <p>{{ i.content }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    showContent(i) {
      i.show = !i.show;
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      contents: false,
      contentInfo: [
        {
          text: "What is Lorem Ipsum?",
          content:
            "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots ",
          show: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Where can I get some?",
          content:
            "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but",
          show: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Once again, when you click on the text, a drop-down menu opens, but when you click on another text, the old menu does not torture, I need the old menu to torture

Comment: You could try using the `onBlur` event? or if you need the event to bubble you can use `focusout` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of hiding all other dropdowns in the same `showContent()` method. You can pass the current index instead of `i` into it, so that you have access to the index for comparison:

```
<div
  v-for="(i, index) in contentInfo"
  :key="index"
  @click="showContent(index)"
  class="dropdown"
>
```

Then in your `showContent` method:

```
showContent(currentIndex) {
  this.contentInfo.forEach((entry, index) => {
    // Toggle current dropdown
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      entry.show = !entry.show;
    } else {
      // Hide all other dropdowns
      entry.show = false;
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to make it concise, it is a simple one-liner:

```
showContent(currentIndex) {
    this.contentInfo.forEach((entry, index) => entry.show = (index === currentIndex ? !entry.show : false));
}
```